# HTML2canvas screenshot does not render full div, only displays what is visible on screen?

Tags: javascript, html, html2canvas

I am using html2canvas to take screenshot of a particular

```
<script>
  function genScreenshot() {
    html2canvas(document.getElementById('option1'), {
      onrendered: function(canvas) {
      
      if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE ") > 0 || 
          navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./)) 
      {
        var blob = canvas.msToBlob();
        window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob,'Test file.png');
      }
      else {
        $('#test').attr('href', canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));
            $('#test').val(canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));
      document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
      }
      
      
      }
    });
}
</script>
```

Above is the javascript used. If i click to take screenshot it shows only div part that is visible on pc screen.

[image: Html2canvas screenshot]

Help me sort out the issue...

Comment: Isn't that the idea of a "screenshot", to show what is currently on the screen ..?

Comment: Actually i need to take a screenshot of a div. While clicking the button part of div not visible in pc

Comment: Yes, I understood that, but then it is not a "screenshot", it's an image of the div.